# not able to delete the row which is added dynamically

Tags: jquery

I am trying to delete the row which is added dynamically using jquery. So when i click on delete image it should remove the corresponding row. But my code is not working. Please someone help me to find my bug.

```js
$("body").on("click", "#tab_logic .del", function() { 
 alert("i am");
 $("tab_logic").parents("tr").remove();
 alert("worked"); // not executing because of above code
});
```

Comment: `$("tab_logic").closest("tr").remove();` use closest

Answer (score 0):

Use [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

> Description: For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

```
$("tab_logic").closest("tr").remove();
```

Comment: What kind of selector is used in this  `$("tab_logic")` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("tab_logic") //Is that a valid selector? that supposed to be starts with # as per your code block.
$("body").on("click", "#tab_logic .del", function() { $("#tab_logic").parents("tr").remove();}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `this`.

When click event is raised on the element with class `del`, the callback will have that element in its context and you can use it to write your logic.

So instead of :

```
 $("tab_logic").parents("tr").remove();
```

use

```
 $(this).parents("tr").remove();
```

Here is the working sample, since you did not provide html, i just assumed a simple test.

```js
$("body").on("click", "#tab_logic .del", function() { 
 $(this).parents("tr").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tab_logic" border=1>
<tr><td>Data1</td><td><a href="#" class="del">Delete</a></td></tr>
<tr><td>Data2</td><td><a href="#" class="del">Delete</a></td></tr>
<tr><td>Data3</td><td><a href="#" class="del">Delete</a></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

if your rows is coming dynamically then you have to write your jquery code in

$(document).on('click','selector',function(){
 
//write your remove row code here

});